# SQL count of 90 day gaps between records

Tags: sql

Say I have a Payment table.  I need to know the number of times the gap between payments is greater than 90 days grouped by personID.  Payment frequency varies.  There is no expected number of payments.  There could 0 or hundreds of payments in a 90 day period.  If there was no payment for a year, that would count as 1. If there was a payment every month, the count would be 0.  If there were 4 payments the first month, then a 90 day gap, then 2 more payments, then another 90 day gap, the count would be 2.

```
CREATE TABLE Payments
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(ID),
    CreateDate datetime
)
```

Comment: Since your question has no specifics (see comments above) I can only provide a general approach with no SQL. You need to arrange the payments sequentially for each client or self-join each row to the chronological "next" one. Then for each of these pair of rows, use DBMS-specific date functions to determine the number of days between their dates, keeping only those with >= 90 days difference. Then group by personID and count the number.

Comment: Just looking for a general approach. Table structure: ID, PersonID, CreateDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2014, you can use the `LAG` or `LEAD` function to peek at other rows, making this easy:

```
Select PersonId, Sum(InfrequentPayment) InfrequentPayments
from
(
    select PersonId
    , case 
        when dateadd(day,@period,paymentdate) < coalesce(lead(PaymentDate) over (partition by personid order by PaymentDate),getutcdate()) 
        then 1 
        else 0 
      end InfrequentPayment
    from @Payment
) x
Group by PersonId
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/491

**Explanation:**

The outer SQL is fairly trivial; we take the results of the inner SQL, group by PersonId, and count/sum the number of times they've paid payment judged as Infrequent.

The inner SQL is also simple; we're selecting every record, making a note of the person and whether that payment (or rather the delay after that payment) was judged infrequent.

The case statement determines what constitutes an infrequent payment.
Here we say that if the record's paymentdate plus 90 days is still earlier than the next payment (or current date if it's the last payment, so there's no next payment) then it's infrequent (1); otherwise it's not (0).

The `coalesce` is simply there to handle the last record for a person; i.e. so that if there is no next payment the current date is used (thus capturing anyone who's last payment was over 90 days before today).

Now for the "clever" bit: `lead(PaymentDate) over (partition by personid order by PaymentDate)`.
`LEAD` is a new SQL function which lets you look at the record after the current one (`LAG` is to see the previous record).
If you're familiar with `row_number()` or `rank()` you may already understand what's going on here.
To determine the record after the current one we don't look at the current query though; rather we specify an `order by` clause just for this function; that's what's in the brackets after the `over` keyword.
We also want to only compare each person's payment dates with other payments made by them; not by any customer.  To achieve that we use the `partition by` clause.

I hope that makes sense / meets your requirement.  Please say if anything's unclear and I'll try to improve my explanation.

---

**EDIT**

For older versions of SQL, the same effect can be achieved by use or `ROW_NUMBER` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`; i.e.

```
;with cte (PersonId, PaymentDate, SequenceNo) as
(
    select PersonId
    , PaymentDate
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PersonId order by PaymentDate)
    from @Payment
)
select a.PersonId
, sum(case when dateadd(day,@period,a.paymentdate) < coalesce(b.paymentdate,getutcdate()) then 1 else 0 end) InfrequentPayments
from cte a
left outer join cte b 
on b.PersonId = a.PersonId 
and b.SequenceNo = a.SequenceNo + 1
Group by a.PersonId
```

Another method which should work on most databases (though less efficient)

```
select PersonId
, sum(InfrequentPayment) InfrequentPayments
from 
(
    select PersonId
    , case when dateadd(day,@period,paymentdate) < coalesce((
        select min(PaymentDate) 
        from @Payment b 
        where b.personid = a.personid
        and b.paymentdate > a.paymentdate
    ),getutcdate()) then 1 else 0 end InfrequentPayment
    from @Payment a
) x
Group by PersonId
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic query for this problem given a `timestamp` field would be something like this:

```
SELECT p1.personID, COUNT(*)
FROM payments p1
JOIN payments p2 ON
  p1.timestamp < p2.timestamp
  AND p1.personID = p2.personID
  AND NOT EXISTS (-- exclude combinations of p1 and p2 where p exists between them
   SELECT * FROM payments p 
   WHERE p.personID = p1.personID
   AND p.timestamp > p1.timestamp 
   AND p.timestamp < p2.timestamp)
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(p2.timestamp, p1.timestamp) >= 90
GROUP BY p1.personID
```